# ISA card in 64 bit Windows support

Tags: windows, 64-bit

Is it possible to support an ISA card in 64 bit windows versions?

Comment: Depends if there are drivers from teh card manufacturer.  More info on the card may assist

Answer (score 5):

Technically possible: Yes.

However:

- Good luck finding new hardware which is modern enough to have a 64 bit CPU yet still has ISA slots. Or replacements for them when they die.
- ISA is limited to 16 MB address space. Thus the driver for the device will need to use [bounce buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering). That will limit performance.
- Finding the X64 drivers for the device can be *interesting*.